# Generic class that extends its type parameter

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript 2.x, is it possible to have a generic/parametric `class` which `extends` its own type parameter?

Something like `class C<T implements I> extends T {}`

What I'm trying to achieve in more detail:

```
interface ConnectionImpl {
  connect(address): Promise<ConnectionImpl>
}
class HTTPConnection implements ConnectionImpl {
  connect(url: string): Promise<HTTPConnection> { ... }
}
class Connecton<T implements ConnectionImpl> extends T {
  constructor(private address) {}
  handshake(key: number): Promise<Token> { 
    return this.connect(this.address)
      .then(...)
  }
}
let conn = new Connection<HTTPConnection>("...")
```

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Added more details to the question about what I'm trying to achieve